# Buffered Writer occasionally creates symbols rather than numbers

Tags: java, io, notepad, bufferedwriter, wordpad

So I have a program that collects a bunch of data and continuously concatenates the data into a string with a single white space between each entry.  During my close routine I print the String into a txt file using buffered writer. About 50% of the time the data shows up as (mostly) Chinese symbols.  Is the VM doing some weird Unicode stuff? Why does this only occur sometimes?

I've looked around on other forums and have not seen other instances of this problem.  None of the other CS majors I know understand what is happening.

EDIT : the data is all integer numbers ranging 0-1365;

UPDATE: upon further research I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38779757/buffered-writer-now-writing-to-file?rq=1) which makes me think a may need a PrintStream rather than a BufferedWriter can anyone speak to that? I tested the PrintStream and I will not be able to construct it with a FileWriter as I would a BufferedWriter which means I need more research to write to my txt.

UPDATE: printing to the console does not make this error occur. I will accept an answer that explains way Notepad (the program I am using to open the txt) sometimes displays numbers and sometimes displays symbols.

Here is the relevant code:

```
 //fields
private static BufferedWriter out;
private File saveFile;
String data;
 //inside constructor 
this.saveFile = new File("C:\\Users\\HPlaptop\\Desktop\\MouseData.txt");
                this.saveFile.delete();
                try{this.saveFile.createNewFile();}
                catch (IOException e ){System.out.println("File creation error");}
try {out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\HPlaptop\\Desktop\\MouseData.txt"));}
                catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("IO Error");}
                this.control.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
                {
                 public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
                    { //there is a method call here but the basics are below
                        out.write(data);
                    out.close();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
```

Here is an example data set printed correctly:

```
 1365 767 1365 767 1365 767 1364 767 1353 756 1268 692 1114 604 980 488 812 334 744 283 694 244 593 150 473 81 328 13 207 0 124 0 115 0 102 0 99 6 107 13 132 20 173 32 187 31 190 25 194 20 201 17 215 14 221 10 224 7 224 7 224 7 226 6 226 6 226 6 226 6 226 6 226 6 226 6
```

This data set was taken seconds later and is not what I want

```
㐀ㄹ㈠㤰㐠㔸㈠㈱㐠㠶㈠㐱㐠㘲㈠㘰㌠㠷ㄠ㔹㌠㌳ㄠ㌹㈠㘹㈠㄰㈠㠷㈠㜳㈠㐶㈠㐷㈠㐶㈠㔷㈠㌶㈠㔵㈠㐵㈠㠰㈠㤴ㄠ㔲㈠㤴㐠‶㐲‹㌱㈠㘴〠㈠㘴〠㈠㘴〠㈠㜴〠㈠㠴〠㈠㠴〠㈠㜴㠠㈠㔴ㄠ‶㐲‵㤱㈠㔴ㄠ‹㐲‵㠱㈠㜴ㄠ‶㐲‹ㄱ㈠〵ㄠ‰㔲‰〱
```

Comment: Also although it is about 50% it is not every other time

Comment: What makes you think the data itself isn't weird chinese symbols? I'd be less inclined to blame it on the BufferedWriter than the data

Comment: good point I edited my question; the data is all integer numbers ranging from 0-1356; I did not include all the code because it would be too long

Comment: Define 'integer numbers ranging from 0-1356`. `BufferedWriter` is for character data, not integer numbers. Are you perhaps looking for `BufferedOutputStream`? or `DataOutputStream`? NB `createNewFile()` is both pointless and wasteful here. `new FileWriter()` already does that, and now you're forcing another deletion.

Comment: @EJP as stated the data is concatenated into a string before being written.

Comment: @Czarking That doesn't answer the question. *What* data is concatenated into a string? If it's binary, it won't work, and isn't supposed to. If it's ASCII digits separated by printable characters, it is impossible to see how this problem could possibly arise. You need to define 'integer numbers'. As requested.

Comment: @EJP they are coordinate points separated by whitespace but I also tried commas

Comment: added example data sets  @Stoud

Comment: Does printing to the console have the same result as to a file?

Comment: Just tested printing to the console and the error does not occur if I use System.out.print rather than out.write() @Stoud

Comment: What application are you using to open it? Try using an alternate one.

Comment: sorry what is "it" my script or the text file? @Stoud

Comment: The text file at C:\\Users\\HPlaptop\\Desktop\\MouseData.txt

Comment: oh interesting, if I open the data/txt file with notepad is sometimes reads as symbols but with wordpad it seems to always open as numbers I will confirm with further testing. @Stoud

Comment: Seems like that should fix your problem, it appears to be some sort of problem with notepad interpreting data.

Comment: @Stoud I wrote answer explaining what we discussed in the comments but should anyone write an answer explain why this happens sometimes I will accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BufferedWriter is not making an error and the code is correct except for 
the redundancy of using

```
this.saveFile.delete();
 try{this.saveFile.createNewFile();}
                catch (IOException e ){System.out.println("File creation error");}
```

and

```
new FileWriter
```

The error in reading the data occurs when the file is opened.  The depending on what program opens the data different results are displayed because of the way the software reads the data.  Notepad was displaying symbols because it interpreted the numbers as ASCII.  The console did not try to interpret the data and just displayed what was written to it.  Using a program that does not try to interpret the numbers in the file will allow the data to be viewed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide and example of what data you write into the stream, you are probably experiencing the *bush hid the facts* phenomenon.